# Как сократить число дуг в орграфе с сохранением «степени» вершин?

Tags: графы, алгоритм

Введем понятие "степени" вершины *d(x)* ориентированного графа как разницу полустепени исхода и полустепени захода. Простыми словами: *d(x) = сумма_весов_исходящих_дуг - сумма_весов_входящих_дуг*
Получается, что сумма "степеней" всех вершин равна нулю.
[Это выглядит примерно так](http://cs622329.vk.me/v622329778/2361f/Z7k3qTRtHJ4.jpg)
Задача: построить на основе заданного графа новый граф с таким же набором вершин с такими же d(x), но с минимальным числом дуг и с минимально возможными весами этих дуг.

[Пример](http://cs622329.vk.me/v622329778/236b5/ywYO-tUg6ps.jpg)

Дискретную математику изучал сравнительно давно и многое забыл уже. Такая задача всплыла в моем проекте. Сам сходу решить не смог, а что-то подобное не могу найти, но есть ощущение, что это какая-то классическая задача. Прошу прощения, если не использовал устоявшуюся терминологию.

Comment: да, чтото похоже связанное с разбиениями.  как разбить положительные и отрицательные вершины на уравновешивающие друг друга куски, и по возможности помельче.  вообще должен получиться двудольный граф, ну если есть нулевые вершины то ещо с добавлением отдельно лежащих вершин.